# Box2D Emscripten: what is box2d.clean.h, and how to successfully generate it?

Tags: javascript, c++, compilation, box2d, emscripten

I am likely missing something simple but I can't really figure it out.

This is from [the makefile](https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js/blob/master/Makefile):

```
box2d.clean.h:
    cpp -x c++ -DEM_NO_LIBCPP -IBox2D_v2.2.1 root.h > box2d.clean.h
```

Let's take a look at [root.h](https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js/blob/master/root.h):

```
// Prevent some inclusions
#define NDEBUG

#ifdef EM_NO_LIBCPP
#define _FEATURES_H
#define _GLIBCXX_CMATH
#define _GLIBCXX_CXX_CONFIG_H
#define _CPP_TYPE_TRAITS_H
#define _EXT_TYPE_TRAITS
#define _GLIBCXX_NUMERIC_LIMITS
#define __GNUC_PREREQ(x, y) 0
#define _STL_RELOPS_H
#define _STL_PAIR_H
#define _FUNCTEXCEPT_H
#define _EXT_NUMERIC_TRAITS
#define _STL_ITERATOR_BASE_TYPES_H
#define _STL_ITERATOR_H
#endif

#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>
```

Okay. Yes I see that we are preventing the inclusion of several headers by defining their include guards. Headers like `<Features.h>`.

My questions:

What purpose might preventing the inclusion of these headers serve?

What command should `cpp` be aliased to? On my machine I see this output:

```
cpp -x c++ -DEM_NO_LIBCPP -IBox2D_v2.2.1 root.h > box2d.clean.h
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: c: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: c++: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: warning: '-x -x' after last input file has no effect
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
```

Why would `gcc` be looking for `c`?

Comment: Hi Steven. I saw your question the other day about creating polygon/chain shapes. I have also been looking into using this Emscripten port for Box2D recently and probably hitting the same snags as you. I started an issue on the Emscripten github you may be interested in: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/629 (no answers yet though :)

Comment: Wow, that's great, you got a bit further than me, I have only been working on emscripten-box2d for the past week in my off-time. Great job, and the little demo page you put together is pretty sweet! My primary snag was the Float64Array problem. Were you able to just replace references to it with Float32Array and everything turns out good? Box2D only uses single precision anyway. Also, are you able to get a mousejoint working yet?

Comment: Also thanks for the upvote on that question. Must have been you :) The primary reason why I was trying to compile from emcc here (this question) was because I wanted to try it without the typed arrays. I was actually able to get past the actual problem with `cpp`, but I'm probably going to want to use the typed arrays anyway so this all is moot.

Comment: About mousejoint, not really. I can get the joint created and it functions correctly, but I am stuck with a b2Joint instead of a b2MouseJoint object, so I cannot SetTarget to make it move around when the user moves the mouse. Yes, I replace Float64Array with Float32Array in the final output js after Emscripten has done its thing.

Comment: @iforce2d Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12874619/340947 Can you try obtaining the pointer value (integer) and use wrapPointer with b2MouseJoint? Should probably work.

Comment: ah, now that looks useful. I didn't notice the setValue function. btw I got an answer on my issue saying 'embind' will be a better solution, will have to look into that.

Comment: @iforce2d Did you need to recompile box2d.js with emscripten in order to be able to create a b2MouseJointDef? Currently I'm stuck in between box2dweb (which has good mousejoint support but no good edge chain shape support) and emscriptening box2d (which I havent been able to successfully compile myself). If you had successfully compiled box2d.js with changes to get the mousejoint initialized could you perhaps send it to me?

Comment: You can find it here http://www.iforce2d.net/emscripten/test.html I used your method for creating loop/polygon shapes, and I figured out how to cast joints properly. Only mouse,revolute and wheel joints are implemented right now. I'm writing up some general usage info and will try to submit a pull request with the other joints implemented today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the `cpp` command by removing the space between `-x` and `c++`.

`cpp -xc++ -DEM_NO_LIBCPP -IBox2D_v2.2.1 root.h > box2d.clean.h`